# How to apply autocorrection in HSL and HSV color spaces?

Tags: graphics, hsv, hsl, cgcolorspace

For correcting contrast in RGB we must apply function
`y = (x - min)*255/(max-min)`
for each channel R, G and B

In YCbCr it is applied to the Y only

How should it work with HSL and HSV?

Maybe we should apply it to some combination of Saturation and Value (Luminance)?